# How does jackson @JsonGetter and @JsonSetter work

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am using jackson 2.10.0 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.10.0), following is a simple test case

The Person class is defined as follows, for the setters, I have used the @JsonSetter annotation, and didn't use @JsonGetter for the getters,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @JsonSetter("first_name")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @JsonSetter("last_name")
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Then, I create a Person object ,and serialize it as string,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class Person3Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setFirstName("abc");
        p.setLastName("def");
        String str = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(p);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

It will call Person's getters, since it doesn't use @JsonGetter, so I think the output should be

```
{"firstName":"abc","lastName":"def"}
```

But, I am surprised to find that it is :

```
{"first_name":"abc","last_name":"def"}
```

It looks that the @JsonSetter has affected the getter output, I would ask what's the behavior here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@JsonSetter` will effect during serialization also [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1519) is the github issue, if you want different name just use another annotation `@JsonGetter` on `get` method

> Documentation may be wrong; @JsonSetter does not only affect deserialization. While it can indeed be used for asymmetric naming (similar to @JsonProperty itself with "split" annotation), its scope is not limited.
>   It may have been at some point, but after unification of property handling (in 1.8 or so), there is less separation between various property accessors.
>
> I can review Javadocs to make it clear that none of annotations is strictly limited in scope -- some may only be relevant to one or the other, but none is intentionally separated.

Comment: I was depressed for a long time

Comment: I have had this problem for a long time. Is there a good solution? Although adding @Jsongetter can solve it, it is too troublesome when there are many fields.